# how can I resolve this warning: SweetAlert2: Unknown parameter "onOpen"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert, sweetalert2

my sweet alert show this warning, how can I resolve this? any idea
[image]
[image]

don't know what causes this warning when I fire this Sweet Alert, it shows this warning.

here is the alert component code:

```
    import Swal from "sweetalert2";

const ToastComponent = Swal.mixin({
  toast: true,
  position: "top-end",
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 3000,
  timerProgressBar: true,
  onOpen: (toast) => {
    toast.addEventListener("mouseenter", Swal.stopTimer);
    toast.addEventListener("mouseleave", Swal.resumeTimer);
  },
});

export const Alert = (type = "", title = "", description = "") =>
  Swal.fire(title, description, type);

export const Toast = (type = "", title = "") =>
  ToastComponent.fire({
    icon: type,
    title,
  });
```

Comment: Please give some of your codes. But, did you make use of *onOpen* correct? It should be look like ```Swal.fire({ didOpen: () => { //Your codes here... } })```

Comment: I have edited the question with the alert component code, please have a look. @newbee

Comment: Does it go away when you remove `onOpen` prop?

Comment: what is your sweetalert2 version?

Comment: my sweetaert2 version is "11.3.0" I have also removed the `onOpen` prop but still got the warning. @MikeSzyndel, @Asgar

Comment: I add answer @Dawood Ahmad.

Answer (score 2):

In case of *onOpen* didn't work, I think you can use *didOpen*.

*From*

```
onOpen: (toast) => {
  toast.addEventListener("mouseenter", Swal.stopTimer);
  toast.addEventListener("mouseleave", Swal.resumeTimer);
}
```

*To*

```
didOpen: (toast) => {
  toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
  toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
}
```

I made a playground here.
[Codepen.](https://codepen.io/neyubee/pen/XWxrzrz)